PDF document with hidden information
When I import certain PDF documents using Power Query (in either Excel or Power BI desktop), there is information present that is not visible using a pdf viewer.
To obtain this PDF document, at my bank site I select to pop up the Bill Pay payee information. This appears in a pop-up "Box". I then select the information in the box and opt to Print --> save as PDF.
When I view the PDF (using Acrobat or Power PDF), what I see is only what I selected.
But when I open the PDF in Power Query, there are additional Pages which seems to contain the unselected information, not in the pop-up box, that was on that screen.
Has anyone an explanation for this?
Due to the sensitivity of the information, I cannot supply a sample document.

It's just part of how your bank's website and your browser generates the PDF. You can try opening one in a text editor to see where and how that "hidden" information is stored, but PDF files aren't very human-readable. It's very possible that the entire page is saved, but the PDF only includes display information for the part you selected. Power Query just imports all the available data

@Cpt.Whale Thank you for that information. I guess I'd need to be knowledgeable about the inner workings of the pdf format to analyze it. Opening the file with either a text editor or even a hex editor doesn't show anything useful. AAMOF, even displayed characters are not found, so maybe it's just an image file that the bank generates. Oh well, I can deal with the issue. And one of these days I may look at it closer.

If you run cpdf -output-json in.pdf -o out.pdf you can see the internal structure of the PDF in JSON format. Or, to also parse the page contents, run cpdf -output-json in.pdf -output-json-parse-content-streams -o out.pdf. You can then extract the information, or edit the JSON and recreate the PDF with cpdf -j out.json -o out.pdf.

@johnwhitington Thank you so much for that information. I don't have the Coherent PDF tool installed, but I'll take a look at that the next rainy day.
